# Accessing the elements of a list of values

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of polynomials (all with the variable `x`) called `lyle` and a function that accesses this list and evaluates it at certain value, but after I do that the polynomials are permanently evaluated at that value given before. How do I fix this? Here's the function:

```
ChebyChase[n_, p_] := (Block[{x}, comb = lyle[[n + 1]]; x = p; Return[comb];])
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue you say that you have. Can you post a small working example? You could also use `ChebyChase[n_, p_] := lyle[[n+1]] /. x -> p` instead.

Comment: Your code is overly complicated, just use `Block[{x = p}, lyle[[n + 1]]]` but I suspect the real problem is previous definitions of your function so evaluate `ClearAll[ChebyChase]` and try your definition again.

Comment: Sorry, I was testing it too, and it doesn't change the values in lyle. The bulk of my code (not shown) somehow changes the values in lyle. The function seems to work though. I'll have to figure how what's going on in the rest of the code.

Comment: Perhaps you have a `=` instead of a `==` in the "bulk" of your code.